# What should I do to save myself from legal trouble when I'm using iPod in my domain name

Tags: trademark

I had registered a domain with "iPod" in it something similar like ipod-to-pc.com in January 2013. At that time I was unaware that using someone's trademark is not okay. I sell some desktop programs that transfer files between iPod and PC via this website. I get around 1000 visitors per day and earn 400-500 USD per month from this website. Now it's not practically possible to shut down this website and start a new one from scratch. Will I likely to get legal notice from Apple asking me to shut down this site? What would you do if you were in my position?

P.S. In a footer I have text that says "iPod®, iPhone®, iPad®, iTunes® and Mac® are trademarks of Apple Inc., registered in the U.S. and other countries. This website is not developed by or affiliated with Apple Inc."

The person in the duplicate question is asking if it's okay to register a domain with trademark in it whereas I want to know what I do if I'm already running a website with a trademark in it's domain name.

Comment: Should be moved.

Comment: Do you mean I should start a new site with different domain and redirect the old one?

Comment: No, this question should be moved to another site ;)

Comment: Good job marking this as a duplicate, @bybe. Never knew about this post.

Comment: So you are here just to say this question should be moved? Wow, you guys are really helpful. Couldn't ask for more

Comment: If you want an answer, you should ask a question the right way.